# How to invalidate cache in apollo?

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo

does anyone knows how to perform cache invalidation in `apollo`?

I'm setting cache hints in resolvers:

```
export default (root, args, { userId }, { cacheControl }) => {
  cacheControl.setCacheHint({ maxAge: 60 });

  return userId && Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
};
```

But if something is changes and `maxAge` is big enough changes would not be reflected.

I'm now thinking about calling `cacheControl.setCacheHint({ maxAge: 0 })` in mutations, are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: I got the same problem, did you solve the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this: https://github.com/lucasconstantino/apollo-cache-invalidation#readme

You can use the Function matching

```
const randomKeyMatch = key => Math.random() >= 0.5

const update = invalidateFields(() => [
  [randomKeyMatch, 'happy']
])

client.mutate({ mutation, update })
```

Comment: I think the author want to invalidate the cache should be transparent to client. But this solution need client to do something.